# MS Word 2003: Page-break before heading splits it over both pages

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2003

I use shading in heading styles. Making a page break from cursor positioned left of heading splits the heading style over two pages. From cursor position on line above the heading, an extra normal-styled line is inserted on top of next page before the heading.

So how can I make the page break set the heading on top of the next page, without being split over previous page?

Need a page break:
[image]

Fail:
[image]

Fail:
[image]

Formatting shown: 
Putting cursor on page-break line the Heading style is highlighted in styles and formatting-tab.
 [image]

Comment: Have you checked if the page break line is formatted with the heading style? (Turn on "formatting marks" and highlight the line that says ------Page Break------- and check which style is applied there.)

Comment: @eckberg Yes it is. See edit.

Comment: And what if you change the style for the page break line to Normal or equivalent?

Comment: @eckberg Then also the heading on next page is changed. Same if I first have no heading, make a page break, then type a heading on top of next page, and change to Heading1 style, the same result with the page break line being formatted to Heading1 also.

Comment: OK, I seem to be able to reproduce it. You does not seem to have a line break after the page break. What if you place the cursor at the beginning of the heading text and press enter, then change the style of the page break line?

Comment: @eckberg This produces the result of the third image (doesn't it?), with an empty line and rather large gap down to the Heading. Maybe that's how Word is designed, that you can't have the heading on the first line, but that looses a lot of space, if a standard sized Top margin is used. It's not just a line, but basically two lines extra, since it's a new paragraph. Or I guess it's more accurate to say it's just an artifact of using shading in the styles, as otherwise the page-break line is obviously invisible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the heading text, and under Paragraph... > Line and Page Breaks > Pagination, enable "Page break before":

[image]

This will add a page break before the selected paragraph.

Result:

[image]

If you want every Header 1 to be preceded by a page break, you could set "Page break before" in the "Paragraph..." options of the Header 1 style.